# Wie erklären sich die verschiedenen Pluralformen für das Wort "Bank"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Lt. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemie) handelt es sich bei dem Wort *Bank* im Sinne von einerseits *Geldinstitut* und andererseits *Sitzgelegenheit* etymologisch um ein Wort. Wie ist dann die unterschiedliche Pluralbildung zu erklären (*Banken* vs. *Bänke*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiktionary hat dazu einen Eintrag: [Bank](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bank)

"Bank/Bänke" kommt von althochdeutsch *banc* „Erhöhung“.

"Bank/Banken" kommt von italienisch *banco* „Tisch“ für „Geldhandelsort“, „Vorratsplatz“. Dem italienischen Wort liegt althochdeutsch *banc* / *bank* zugrunde.

Durch das Wort "bankrott" ließe sich vielleicht eine Verbindung herstellen; es kommt angeblich von "banco rotto" = "zerbrochener Tisch" (des Geldwechslers).

Siehe dazu auch [hier](http://www.nbbmuseum.be/de/2008/01/money-changers-bench.htm), wo es heißt:

> *Woher kommt eigentlich der Begriff “Bankrott”? Die Antwort auf diese Frage führt zum Wechseltisch zurück. Hatte ein Geldwechsler verglichen
>   mit seinen Einlagen zu viele Darlehen gewährt, durfte er seinen Beruf
>   nicht länger ausüben. Damit potenzielle Kunden wussten, dass ein
>   Geldwechsler bankrott war, wurde sein Tisch entzwei gebrochen. Solche
>   zerbrochenen Tische werden auf Italienisch “banco rotto” (zu dt.
>   “Bankrott”) genannt.*

Jedenfalls dürfte es sich um zwei verschiedene Ursprünge handeln.

Comment: Aha - dann verstehe ich auch "Sandbank" besser. Allerdings sehe ich dann einen Zusammenhang mit "Geld auf der hohen Kante haben". Die unterschiedlichen Pluralformen sind für mich damit aber nicht geklärt.

Comment: Die Angelegenheit mit den verschiedenen Ursprüngen wäre noch zu klären. Im Etymologie-Buch der Duden-Reihe findet man 'Auch unser Wort Bank "Geldinstitut" gehört zu dieser Reihe. Es ist seinem Ursprung nach identisch mit Bank "Sitzbank", dessen germanische Vorformen früh ins Roman. entlehnt wurden (it. banca, banco). Aus dem It. wurde das Wort mit der dort entwickelten Bedeutung "langer Tisch des Geldwechslers" im 15. Jh. rückentlehnt, einer Bedeutung, die noch im Mittelhochdeutschen wehselbanc vorliegt.'

Comment: Auch (interessant!): 'Die Bank als Geldinstitut und die Gartenbank sind verwandte Wörter. 
Die Geldwechsler auf den spätmittelalterlichen Märkten – man nannte 
sie Lombarden, weil sie oft aus Oberitalien kamen -  breiteten ihre 
Instrumente (Waagen) und ihre Münzen und Wertpapiere auf einer 
Holzbank aus. Es kam vor, dass eine solche Bank Pleite, Bankrott 
machte, dann hieß es eben „Banca rotta“ (Bank kaputt).'

Comment: @userunknown: Die "hohe Kante" ist ein [typische Merkmal von Truhen](http://media03.myheimat.de/2010/07/23/1172932_web.jpg), in denen die Menschen ja früher all ihr Hab und Gut aufbewahrten. Geld hat man wohl eher dort abgelegt, als es in der Truhe unter die Sachen zu wühlen.

Comment: Olaf, dass die Rückentlehnung mit einem anderen Plural daherkommt als das ursprüngliche Wort ist doch nicht verwunderlich, oder?